# Watson Speech to Text - Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL contains a fragment identifier

Tags: javascript, websocket, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, node-red

I'm trying to connect the Watson Speech to Text API, however I'm getting the following error for Firefox and Chrome.
Note: It was working fine before, maybe some updates in the websocket terms.
I appreciate your help!

```
var token = "{{payload}}";  
var model = "en-US_BroadbandModel"; // Change to your own model
var wsURI = 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?watson-token=' +
                token + '&model=' + model;

var ws = new WebSocket(wsURI);
```

the error is being identified in this line:

```
var ws = new WebSocket(wsURI);
```

Browsers console errors:

```
Firefox: "SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified"

Chrome: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The 
  URL contains a fragment identifier ('x3D;&model=en-US_BroadbandModel').
  Fragment identifiers are not allowed in WebSocket URLs."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to escape the token, have you tried that?

btw. have you tried the Watson Javascript SDK https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk ? it deals with these lower level details for you.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for replay, As I'm not much experienced with Node JS, I'm implementing this code in Node Red, So the whole code is in a node template, just for close this question I could solve my problem just adding 1 (one) more (}) in the payload token variable, See how this is now:                                                                                    var token = "{{{payload}}}";